# SweetAlerts Ajax With PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sweetalert

So currently I am trying to have a SweetAlert pop up that has you enter a key to access the website. I want to have it setup so you put in the key and it runs an AJAX request on a separate PHP page that then returns true or false if that key exists. I did try to use the SweetAlerts example but it is continually erroring out.

JavaScript:

```
function SignUp() {
            swal({
                text: 'Enter Your 8-Digit Beta Key',
                content: "input",
                button: {
                    text: "Submit",
                    closeModal: false,
                },
            })
            .then(key => {
                if (!key) throw null;

                return fetch(`beta/database.php?mode=key&key=${key}`);
            })
            .then(results => {
                return results.json();
            })
            .then(json => {
                const key = json.results[0];
                const result = key.tf;
                if (result == "false") {
                    return swal("Key Invalid", "Key Is Invalid, Have You Already Registered?", "error");
                }

                swal("Key Valid", "Redirecting", "success");
            })
            .catch(err => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    swal("Error", "Something Went Wrong, Try Again Later", "error");
                } else {
                    swal.stopLoading();
                    swal.close();
                }
            });
```

PHP:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(REMOVED FOR PRIVACY);

if($_GET['mode'] === "key") {
    $key = htmlspecialchars($_GET['key']);
    $query = "SELECT beta_key FROM beta_keys WHERE beta_key = '$key'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        die(json_encode(['tf' => "true"]));
    } else {
        die(json_encode(['tf' => "false"]));
    }
}
```

All it does is call the .catch part of the function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share what is erroring? 
IT's hard to guess

Comment: It just shows the error box in the .catch function

Comment: const key = json.result; <- json.result is not defined. You are simply returning a string, not a json object. thus const key = json whould be either "true" or "false". If you want to return json, then in yourr php code add die(json_encode(['result' => "true"]));

Comment: "It just shows the error box in the .catch function" in that case you need to look in your browser's developer tools to find what the actual error is. There's likely to be something in the console, and/or a problem apparent when looking at the ajax request in the network tools. This is a basic debugging task you should learn to do when working with JavaScript.

Comment: Okay so I got it to work when I used json_encode, but now it is always pulling true, that is probably an easy fix and I will try to solve it.

Comment: Something else I feel obliged to mention: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the help, almost forgot about XSS and injections

Comment: There appears to be ticks `\`` in `database.php?mode=key&key=${key}` which I feel should be quotes `'`.

Comment: That isn't breaking it but now the JS things that the result is undefined

Comment: @HaydenStith just to be clear, my comment was about SQL injection, not XSS. There are other steps you can take to prevent XSS

Comment: "the JS things that the result is undefined ". Can you update your code to show how you are now returning the data as valid JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at SweetAlert I have no clue why it is not working but instead, I used the fork [Sweetalert 2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) and it makes it way easier. I have it working with the current PHP and slightly different JS.

```
function SignUp() {
            swal({
                title: 'Enter Your 8-Digit Beta Key',
                input: 'text',
                inputAttributes: {
                    autocapitalize: 'on'
                },
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
                showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                preConfirm: (key) => {
                    return fetch(`beta/database.php?mode=key&key=${key}`)
                    .then(response => {
                        if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error(response.statusText)
                        }
                        return response.json()
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        swal.showValidationError(
                        `Request failed: ${error}`
                        )
                    })
                },
                allowOutsideClick: () => !swal.isLoading()
                }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value.tf == "true") {
                    swal({
                        type: 'success',
                        title: 'Key Valid',
                        text: 'Redirecting',
                        footer: '<a href="#">Click Here To Go There Now</a>'
                    })
                } else if(result.value.tf == "false") {
                    swal({
                        type: 'error',
                        title: 'Key Invalid',
                        text: 'Your Key Is Either Inactive Or Typed Incorrectly.',
                        footer: '<a href="#">Why do I have this issue?</a>'
                    })
                }
            })
        }
```

Hope this makes things easier for people dealing with this same issue.